# How to pause a loop to allow for user selection of variables

Tags: bash

I cannot seem to figure out how to make this loop pause for user selection. It automatically chooses the `*` selection every time. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash    

while read -r lineIn; do 
if [[ "$(cmd_output)" != "" ]]; then
   echo "choose one letter (a)(b)(c)(d)(e)" 
   read abcde  
      case $abcde in
         [aA] ) do stuff and continue the loop;;
         [bB] ) do stuff and do not continue the loop;;
         [cC] ) do other stuff and continue the loop
         [dD] ) do nothing and continue the loop;;
         [eE] ) exit;;  
            * ) echo "Danger Will Robinson!";;
      esac
else
   echo "No output from command!"
fi   
done < filename
```

Comment: 1. Do you really want/need `read -p` ? I think just `read abcde` should work. 2. constructs like `[a | A]` "boil" down to `[aA |]`, so I think you really just need `[Aa]` (etc). Otherwise, looks good. Good Luck!

Comment: The reason I added the `-p` option is because I originally thought it would pause to prompt for user input. But you are right, it is unnecessary.

Comment: for `ksh`, the `read` man page shows that `-p` is to "Read from the current co-process instead of standard input. An end of file causes read to disconnect the co-process so that another can be created.", but it may be different for `bash` (too tired to look right now). Good luck.

Comment: It chooses the `*` every time because there are no `break` commands at the end of the choices within the loop.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Having `break` commands at the end of the choices didn't stop the loop from running unless `break` was on the `*` choice. But doing that breaks out of the entire script. And it would automatically run any command found for choice `*` which could be really bad. Martin's answer has fixed the issue I was having. With `read abcde < /dev/tty` it waits for one the choices to be entered. But also `break` is needed now that it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redirect the "read abcde" to read from the tty.

`read abcde < /dev/tty`

Because of the while loop the stdin is actually coming from the redirect.